# Redirect User to custom page on back button in IE in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

Heloo,

i have 3 pages PageA, Page B, Page C, from PageA user redirect to PageB using Response.Redirect, On Body load of Page B user redirect to Page C, and on Page C user redirect to another external link.
i want to achieve that when user press back button from external link it skip page C and B and directly go to Page A,
I have tried so many thing like history.push and history.replace but no successes.

Comment: It directs from C to external link? How? after some user action? using Response.Redirect?

Comment: No, its submitting form on body load and post to external link.
         <body onload="javascript:document.E_FORM.submit();">
        <form  action="abc.com" method="POST" name="E_FORM">

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Server.Transfer` in Page A and B as it doesn't modify URL and history is not created in browser. But on Page C use `Response.Redirect` because now history should be logged. Now when it browser back button is pressed on external page it will get the user to Page A since browser won't find any history for Page B and C.

Comment: from page A its redirecting using response.redirect but in page B on body load it submit the form and post data to page C

Comment: What you are doing on B? just redirecting?

Comment: no i am populating some hidden fields and then posting that fields to Page C, and same as on C, populating some fields by request and then post to external link.

Comment: Is it possible to populate all fields in same page? Or you have to post data separately?

Comment: OK then, remove form B and use `Server.Transfer` from A and it should be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99110/discussion-between-sohail-hameed-and-imad).

Comment: actually i can not use server.transfer in my application